# Want to launch fossil from a tcl file

Tags: tcl, fossil

Hi I want to launch fossil using a tcl file. I have been trying to run the fossil setting up code like fossil clone using exec in the tcl file but it is not running.

Can anyone please help me in how to run the fossil from a tcl file. So that when I run the file a fossil folder gets created and cloned with the specified repository.

Comment: Can you show us the code that you have tried so far?

Comment: Hey sorry should have added it before. So I have a fossil.exe in a folder f1. The code in the tcl file goes like this... 1. catch {exec path/f1/fossil}   2. catch {exec path/fi/fossil clone repository_path test.fossil}                   3. catch{exec fossil open test.fossil}                                                                                  
I am not sure if this code is exactly right.. Could you please help

Answer (score 1):

The main tricky thing with running fossil as a subprocess is that it likes to sometimes talk to the terminal. The simplest way of dealing with this is to make a small wrapper procedure to hide the magic:

```
set FOSSIL_PATH /path/to/fossil.exe

proc fossil args {
    global FOSSIL_PATH
    exec $FOSSIL_PATH {*}$args <@stdin 2>@stderr
}
```

Then your code can do this:

```
fossil clone $repo repo.fossil
file mkdir repo
cd repo
fossil open ../repo.fossil
```

(Or at least it appears to work for me when I test with `fossil status` in a suitable directory.)